# Adding currents in a three-phase system

Tags: circuit-design, three-phase

I have a single phase installation in my apartment, with 127 V. The electric supplier allows to modify it to 3-phase, with 220 V between phases. It requires a request from an electrician to the supplier.

According to one of the proposals that I get, there will be a 32A 2-phase circuit breaker for the shower, and 2 other smaller for the air conditioner and for the induction cooker. All those devices with 220V. Of course there will remain the other 1-phase circuit breakers for lamps, TV, etc. The main circuit breaker will be also 32A.

I suppose that if I buy a shower of 7000W (32 A max) and feed it with phases A and B, no other electrical device can use this phases. For example, suppose that the air conditioner (8 A max) is connected to B and C. The phase B will have 40 A.

My question is if I can simply add the amps like that, even from a pure resistive circuit as an electric shower and a not pure resistive as an air conditioner.

I understand that the electrician tends to avoid any excessive current out of the apartment. But I am afraid to be limited to a shower of smaller power, otherwise I have to turn off everything to take a hot shower.

Comment: Probably better suited to home improvements stack. https://diy.stackexchange.com/